How do i update this code from vrf version 2 to version 2.5 with the subscription id changes and everything?
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";

contract CoinFlip is VRFConsumerBaseV2 {
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface COORDINATOR;
    IERC20 public token;

    // Chainlink parameters
    uint64 s_subscriptionId;
    bytes32 s_keyHash;
    uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;
    uint32 callbackGasLimit = 100000;
    uint32 numWords = 1;

    address owner;

    struct Bet {
        address player;
        uint256 amount;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Bet) public bets; // maps VRF requestId to bet details

    event BetPlaced(address indexed player, uint256 indexed amount, uint256 indexed requestId);
    event CoinFlipResult(address indexed player, bool won, uint256 indexed amount);

    constructor(
        address _vrfCoordinator,
        bytes32 _keyHash,
        uint64 _subscriptionId,
        address _tokenAddress
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(_vrfCoordinator) {
        COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(_vrfCoordinator);
        s_keyHash = _keyHash;
        s_subscriptionId = _subscriptionId;
        owner = msg.sender;
        token = IERC20(_tokenAddress); // your ERC20 token address
    }

    // Allow users to place their bet (send tokens as a bet)
    function placeBet(uint256 amount) external {
        require(amount > 0, "Bet amount must be greater than zero");
        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount), "Transfer failed");

        uint256 requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
            s_keyHash,
            s_subscriptionId,
            requestConfirmations,
            callbackGasLimit,
            numWords
        );

        bets[requestId] = Bet(msg.sender, amount);
        emit BetPlaced(msg.sender, amount, requestId);
    }

    // Chainlink VRF callback function
    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomWords) internal override {
        Bet memory bet = bets[requestId];
        bool won = randomWords[0] % 2 == 0; // Coinflip: even is win, odd is lose

        if (won) {
            uint256 payout = bet.amount * 2;
            require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= payout, "Contract doesn't have enough tokens");
            token.transfer(bet.player, payout);
            emit CoinFlipResult(bet.player, true, payout);
        } else {
            emit CoinFlipResult(bet.player, false, bet.amount);
        }

        delete bets[requestId]; // Clear bet after resolving
    }

    // Allow owner to withdraw tokens if necessary
    function withdrawTokens(uint256 amount) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can withdraw tokens");
        require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= amount, "Insufficient balance");
        token.transfer(owner, amount);
    }
}```


// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus.sol";
import {VRFV2PlusClient} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/libraries/VRFV2PlusClient.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract CoinFlip is VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus {
    IERC20 public token;

    // Chainlink parameters
    uint256 _subscriptionId,  // Changed to uint256
    bytes32 s_keyHash;
    uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;
    uint32 callbackGasLimit = 100000;
    uint32 numWords = 1;

    address owner;

    struct Bet {
        address player;
        uint256 amount;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Bet) public bets; // maps VRF requestId to bet details

    event BetPlaced(address indexed player, uint256 indexed amount, uint256 indexed requestId);
    event CoinFlipResult(address indexed player, bool won, uint256 indexed amount);

    constructor(
        address _vrfCoordinatorV2Plus,
        bytes32 _keyHash,
        uint256 _subscriptionId,
        address _tokenAddress
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus(_vrfCoordinatorV2Plus) {
        s_keyHash = _keyHash;
        s_subscriptionId = _subscriptionId;
        owner = msg.sender;
        token = IERC20(_tokenAddress); // your ERC20 token address
    }

    // Allow users to place their bet (send tokens as a bet)
    function placeBet(uint256 amount) external {
        require(amount > 0, "Bet amount must be greater than zero");
        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount), "Transfer failed");

        uint256 requestId = s_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            VRFV2PlusClient.RandomWordsRequest({
                keyHash: s_keyHash,
                subId: s_subscriptionId,
                requestConfirmations: requestConfirmations,
                callbackGasLimit: callbackGasLimit,
                numWords: numWords,
                extraArgs: VRFV2PlusClient._argsToBytes(
                    VRFV2PlusClient.ExtraArgsV1({nativePayment: true})
                )
            })
        );

        bets[requestId] = Bet(msg.sender, amount);
        emit BetPlaced(msg.sender, amount, requestId);
    }

    // Chainlink VRF callback function
    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomWords) internal override {
        Bet memory bet = bets[requestId];
        bool won = randomWords[0] % 2 == 0; // Coinflip: even is win, odd is lose

        if (won) {
            uint256 payout = bet.amount * 2;
            require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= payout, "Contract doesn't have enough tokens");
            token.transfer(bet.player, payout);
            emit CoinFlipResult(bet.player, true, payout);
        } else {
            emit CoinFlipResult(bet.player, false, bet.amount);
        }

        delete bets[requestId]; // Clear bet after resolving
    }

    // Allow owner to withdraw tokens if necessary
    function withdrawTokens(uint256 amount) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can withdraw tokens");
        require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= amount, "Insufficient balance");
        token.transfer(owner, amount);
    }
}

They key changes are
1.Changed the base class from VRFConsumerBaseV2 to VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus.
2.Updated the way random words are requested using VRFV2PlusClient.RandomWordsRequest. Added extraArgs for native payment (see the documentation)
3.As for the subscription Id , the data type changed from uint64 ==> uint256
Hope it helps in you updating you code :)
